# Cassandra equivalent of group by

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm in initial stages of data modeling in Cassandra for an application. This application has existing relational persistence layer, which has to be replaced with Cassandra.

Application uses a table named `login_log` for users, which provides last login time for any users in all applications.

Here's the `CQL` that I'm using to create this table

```sql
create table login_log (
    user_id int,
    application_name text,
    login_date timestamp,
    primary key (user_id, application_name, login_date)
) with clustering order by (application_name asc, login_date desc)
```

`user_id` is partition key. `application_name` and `login_date` are clustering keys. This table maintains a history of logins, data is never deleted in it.

I'm trying to retrieve last login date of given `user_id` for all applications in one query.

If I were writing a `SQL` query to do the same it would look something like below

```sql
select user_id, application_name, max(login_date) from login_log group by user_id, application_name
```

However it cannot be done in Cassandra, since there's no group by clause or aggregation functions. Arguably clustering columns are already grouped but I'm unable to create a query which retrieves latest `login_date` for all applications in one query.

If were doing it for one application `CQL` would look like below

```sql
select * from login_log where user_id = ? and application_name = ? limit 1
```

Since cluster are already ordered by `login_date`, `order by` is not needed. I need to extend the same query to retrieve data for all applications in one go.

Is it possible to do this in Cassandra? If not is there a data modeling technique that will allow me to do this?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: `select user_id, application_name, max(login_date) from login_log group by user_id, application_name` would work with an appropriate `max` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GROUP BY is supported from version 3.10 check improvement ticket [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707) and Cassandra [official documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html?highlight=group#grammar-token-group_by_clause).

Comment: When using UDAs or UDFs make sure you're staying within a partition. Cross partiiton UDAs / UDFs will not perform at scale.